# How to correctly plugin in a Reactjs Scroll bar module

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, reactjs, scrollbar

I'm taking the simple [Facebook flux-chat](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat) example and plugging in nicer scroll bars for the "[MessagesSection](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-chat/js/components/MessageSection.react.js)" component

The plugin in for the scrollbars is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbars)

I installed the module, required it in the "MessagesSection" and wrapped the new component around the list of messages like so:

```
render: function() {
    var postListItems = this.state.posts.map(getPostListItem);
    return (
      <div className="post-section">
        <h3 className="post-thread-heading">{this.state.thread.name}</h3>

        <ul className="post-list" ref="postList">
                <ScrollbarWrapper>
                  <div>             
                   {postListItems}
                  </div>
                </ScrollbarWrapper>
        </ul>

        <PostComposer threadID={this.state.thread.id}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Note: I also tried wrapping it around the unordered list as well.

Yet the scroll bars remain unchanged(still the basic chrome ones that were there before).

What am I doing wrong that the scroll bars are not changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy paste this CSS in the index.html: https://github.com/ojame/react-scrollbars/blob/master/examples/views/home/examples/custom-scrollbar.css

And use the class on the wrapper like so: `<ScrollbarWrapper className="ScrollbarContent--custom">`

Comment: Almost there! The old chrome scroll-bar shows up until I mouse over. Also the component window size scrunched down.

Comment: It's not getting there that is important, becoming better at getting there is! Good luck ;)

Comment: For anyone who reads this later. Here are the final pieces - change the css file mentioned to match the height of the component and add this so the scroll bar only shows up on hover.                                                                                               .ScrollbarContent--custom {
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: rgb(253, 253, 253);
 }
        .ScrollbarContent--custom:hover {
   overflow: auto;
 }